# The woman pulled back the curtain to disclose the hidden parrot

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language, verb-usage

I am studying a group of synonyms, and have an impression, that ChatGPT gives me the wrong answers. For example, I suspect that this sentence does not sound idiomatic:

**The woman pulled back the curtain to *disclose* the hidden parrot.**

(the source of this sentence is NOT ChatGPT: I simply asked ChatGPT if this sentence was ok)

Comment: You are right. disclose is normally only used about information.

Comment: I think most people would probably use "reveal" here. Or possibly "uncover".

Comment: You are right it's not idiomatic.  ChatGPT is practically useless for learning English or anything for that matter. It basically **parrots** nonsense written on the internet. Excuse the pun.  It should be renamed "artificial unintelligence".

Comment: I've chastised your use of ChatGPT with a downvote, although the question itself is fine, though you should say why you think **disclose** is not idiomatic.

Comment: Whilst I agree that the sentence is not idiomatic and that **reveal** is probably the most common usage, no native speaker would have any difficulty in correctly understanding it.

Comment: You're basically asking us to proof-read AI. You haven't even told us why you 'suspect' it isn't idiomatic.

Comment: Wow. Casting downvotes when a user *openly* says they've used AI as a source in a question. There's no law or rule forbidding its use as long as the user tells the community that their source is ChatGPT. By downvoting you're telling the user to go away. ChatGPT never disparages questions however good or badly researched they may be.

Comment: Having said that, I suspect there's some missing context, and maybe the prompt given to the programme was unclear.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The source is NOT ChatGPT. I gave a list of synonyms and asked ChatGPT to provide the example sentences, then I replaced the word 'reveal' with 'disclose' in one of them and asked ChatGPT if the sentence was OK. It said so, but I had some vague feeling (otherwise I would not have asked you, obviously) that there was something wrong with the usage as I didn't remember reading or hearing this particular usage.

Comment: EDITED: Your question has received four downvotes and one upvote. The downvotes, as proven by a few comments, were probably motivated by you mentioning that you asked an AI programme if "disclose" could legitimately replace "reveal" in a sentence that was created by you. Its response was positive. Your recent edit clarifies the situation and will probably stop the flow of downvotes. But why didn't you first check in a dictionary and added that research in your question?

Comment: ChatGPT is not a source of facts. If it tells you anything true, it’s merely a coincidence. The one thing it is good at is reading and writing grammatical English. It can write very formal robotic-sounding English fairly fluently, but it can’t accurately tell you if what you’ve written is correct or idiomatic.

Comment: Merriam Webster: b: to expose to view. Using an actual dictionary is what works, usually.

Answer (score 2):

The main use of 'disclose' is to tell or make known information (facts, news, etc), especially in a formal context e.g. he *disclosed that he had been to prison* but a secondary, less often used meaning, also somewhat formal, is to physically uncover something or bring it into view. It is perfectly grammatical to use 'disclose' like in the sentence in question, but possibly somewhat formal or old-fashioned.

> disclose in British English VERB (transitive)
>
> 1. to make (information) known
>    **2. to allow to be seen; lay bare**
>
> disclose in American English TRANSITIVE VERB
>
> 1. to make known; reveal or uncover
>    *to disclose a secret*
>    **2. to cause to appear; allow to be seen; lay open to view
>
>    *In spring the violets disclose their fragrant petals***
> 2. obsolete to open up; unfold NOUN
> 3. obsolete disclosure SYNONYMS
> 4. show, tell, unveil. See reveal. 2. expose. ANTONYMS
> 5. conceal.

[Disclose (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disclose)

> disclose verb    (formal)
>
> to give somebody information about something, especially something that was previously secret
>
> **​disclose something**
> **to allow something that was hidden to be seen**

[Disclose (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/disclose)

Comment: Do you mean that 'The woman pulled back the curtain to disclose the hidden parrot.' is fine, though 'somewhat formal'?

Comment: **disclose** is not a word you'd expect to hear from someone  who was unread.

Comment: @TimR You mean, the previous context would have to set the style and show that the speaker is not 'unread' (archaic, isn't it?)?

Comment: @sanya6 - _Do you mean that 'The woman pulled back the curtain to disclose the hidden parrot.' is fine, though 'somewhat formal'?_ - yes, that is exactly what I mean, and what I thought I had written.

Comment: @sanya6  Are you asking if **disclose** is archaic or if **unread** is archaic?  **disclose**, especially in the sense of bringing something literally into view, belongs to a fairly advanced *lexile*.

Comment: And **unread**  (applied to a person who has read very few books) is not archaic unless your definition of "archaic" is "pre-internet".  The unread don't use the word "unread". The word **unread** (in that sense) can be found in many books written during the second half of the 20th century and even today: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22who+is+unread%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=85af15397c77c0f6&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&biw=1356&bih=671&sxsrf=ACQVn0-A2AxLPl7TQ3u51cymahLDImI0Gg%3A1709039425184&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1950%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2020&tbm=bks

Answer (score 1):

The word **disclose** is not in the working vocabulary of a large segment of the population of native speakers.

We can disclose information previously withheld, or disclose a secret.

> The seller failed to disclose  that the car had suffered severe water damage.
>
> She raised her long skirt up to thigh height, disclosing a tattoo of a helmeted chimp riding a mountain bicycle over the knob of her left kneecap.

Comment: My dentist sells me 'disclosing tablets'.

Comment: In the US, going to the dentist is not a regular thing for a large segment of the population.

Comment: Which segment ?

Comment: **disclose** is not usually found in the active vocabulary of adults whose highest level of education is secondary school, and for many of them the sense  "to make something literally visible to the eye which had been hidden" wouldn't be part even of their working vocabulary, though they might know the meaning of "disclose" in its sense of "to make known a relevant fact about the object of a financial transaction", as in *The Seller didn't disclose that the phone's screen was scratched.*